# How to find rows that do not match between two tables P and N

Tags: mysql

**Scenario:**
I created and updated a table so that the new table (N) has some rows that are different from the previous table (P). Now I want to find the rows that have been updated.

I'm running the following now:

```
SELECT N.* 
FROM previous_table P 
JOIN new_table N 
  ON P.item_id = N.item_id 
WHERE (P.column_1 != N.column_1) 
   OR (P.column_2 != N.column_2) 
   OR ... (P.column_n != N.column_N);
```

Right now I only have three columns, so it's working for me but I imagine this method is rather untenable if the number of columns is very large.

Is there a way to simplify the WHERE bit?

Comment: *this method is rather untenable if the number of columns is very large* In any case you must compare all fields. So you must write whole fields list.

Comment: So there is no other way but to explicitly list each column?

Comment: There is a lot of variants, but all of them (exclusion - export data to external CSV files) needs to list each column.

Comment: I see. Looks like there's no two ways about it then. Cheers!

Comment: Can there be rows in P that are missing from N, as in 'deleted'?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT N.* 
FROM new_table N 
LEFT JOIN previous_table P 
     ON P.item_id = N.item_id 
    AND P.column_1 = N.column_1
    AND P.column_2 = N.column_2
    AND /* ... */ P.column_n = N.column_N
WHERE P.item_id IS NULL;
```

or

```
SELECT N.* 
FROM new_table N 
LEFT JOIN previous_table P 
     ON (P.item_id, P.column_1, P.column_2, /* ... , */ P.column_N) 
       =
        (N.item_id, N.column_1, N.column_2, /* ... , */ N.column_N) 
WHERE P.item_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
( SELECT CONCAT_WS("\t", item_id, col1, col2, ...) AS x FROM prev )
UNION ALL
( SELECT CONCAT_WS("\t", item_id, col1, col2, ...) AS x FROM newt )
GROUP BY x
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

should give you the rows that are not the same between the tables.

Notes:

- I assume tab (`\t`) does not show up in any column.
- I don't know what will happen with `NULLs`.
- It shows both the 'before' and 'after' values, without saying which is which.
- New rows and delete rows are included in the output.

If `item_id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, then there is a much better way:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS("\t", prev.col1, prev.col2, ...) AS "PrevValues",
       CONCAT_WS("\t", newt.col1, newt.col2, ...) AS "NewValues"
    FROM prev
    JOIN newt USING(item_id);
```

Notes:

- This won't handle inserts/deletes, however you could get one or the other by using `LEFT` or `RIGHT`.

To get the column list typed out for you:

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(column_name)
    FROM  information_schema.columns
    WHERE  table_schema = '...'   -- your database name
      AND  table_name = '...';    -- your table name
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion. It's a very interesting approach and I certainly wouldn't have thought of that! 

However, it seems to me that I still have to list out all the columns. That is what I meant by my method being 'untenable if the number of columns is very large'. Hypothetically, if I have a hundred columns, I have to type out hundred columns in my select statement.

I'm wondering if there's a way to loop it like a 'for loop':
for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    check prev.column[i] != new.column[i]

Comment: @lardandweed - I added code to generate the list of column names (in a string).  Then copy the output into my `CONCAT_WS` (or other code).

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use the information_schema for this also. So you dont have to write everything done in a query. My suggestion would be something like that:

```
select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME
from information_schema.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='Table_1' and COLUMN_NAME not in(SELECT COLUMN_NAME from 
information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='Table_2')
```

Greetings,
Sebastian